# List counties in current extent using Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, map-book

Maybe I'm just not thinking clearly, but I can't figure this one out.  I need to have a spot on my mapbook pages that says "Counties: " and is automatically filled with the counties in the extent of the current page.  This was SIMPLE with DSMapBook, but I can't seem to replicate it in DataDrivenPages.

Should I just do an intersect and append the new data in a column on my Townships table (Grid layer)?

Answer (score 2):

If scripting the operation is an option, it looks like you can [combine arcpy and Data Driven pages](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisdesktop/archive/2010/12/14/Combining-Data-Driven-Pages-with-Python-and-arcpy.mapping.aspx). Maybe you could somehow select all of your county features in the [current extent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/) of the dataframe, then insert those into a [graphic element](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/GraphicElement/00s300000040000000/).

Answer (score 0):

What I did to accomplish this is run an identity (if you have the appropriate license level) and get each county joined onto your town layer. Using arcpy i wrote a script to do the following.  Write a definition query for that layer using the current ddp as the query.  Run a search cursor and get the value of each county in the queried table. Set each value to append to a text element. You can use \r\n to put each county on a seperate line if you need to.